# SVG transform animations won't work in Safari

Tags: svg, safari, svg-animate

I've got a simple animated SVG that works great in Chrome/Firefox but it doesn't animate at all in Safari.  I understand this is due to SVG 1.1 vs. 2.0 (Safari doesn't yet support 2.0) , and that there are ways to make such animations work (simple scale plus rotate on three separate elements, with different timing) within SVG 1.1 but everything I've tried just fails completely.

Is there any way to get the following SVG 2.0 code to work properly in an SVG 1.1 environment like Safari or do I need to completely recode this in CSS?

Thank you!

```css
body{
  background:#000
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg viewBox="1.691 0 12.029 10.111" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <symbol id="star1" viewBox="0 0 4 4" width="5" height="5">
    <g>
      <path transform-origin="1.5 1.5" fill="white" d="M 0 0 C 1 1 1 2 0 3 C 1 2 2 2 3 3 C 2 2 2 1 3 0 C 2 1 1 1 0 0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0; 1 1; 0 0" keyTimes="0 ; .4 ; 1" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 1.5 1.5; 90 1.5 1.5" keyTimes="0 ; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <symbol id="star2" viewBox="0 0 4 4" width="5" height="5">
    <g>
      <path transform="scale(0 0)" transform-origin="1.5 1.5" fill="white" d="M 0 0 C 1 1 1 2 0 3 C 1 2 2 2 3 3 C 2 2 2 1 3 0 C 2 1 1 1 0 0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0; 1 1; 0 0" keyTimes="0 ; .4 ; 1" dur="3s" begin="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 1.5 1.5; 90 1.5 1.5" keyTimes="0 ; 1" dur="1s" begin="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <use transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2.0000000298023224, 1.0000000149011612)" xlink:href="#star1">
    <animate attributeName="visibility" values="visible;hidden;hidden;visible;hidden;hidden" keyTimes="0;.2;.4;.6;.8;1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <use transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 8.00000011920929, 2.0000000298023224)" xlink:href="#star1">
    <animate attributeName="visibility" values="hidden;visible;hidden;visible;hidden;hidden" keyTimes="0;.2;.4;.6;.8;1" dur="15s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
  <use transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 10.000000149011612, 6.000000089406967)" xlink:href="#star2">
    <animate attributeName="visibility" values="visible;hidden;hidden;visible;hidden;hidden" keyTimes="0;.2;.4;.6;.8;1" dur="15s" begin="1.5s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </use>
</svg>
```

Comment: Works fine on my Safari 17.2.1

Comment: Ah, it looks like the latest version of Safari does support it (thanks!) - but those on older iPads will still have a problem and my audience skews older, less techy, so I'd love to make it compliant with all versions of Safari.

Answer (score 0):

### safari/webkit tends to be less forgiving towards minor syntax errors – or lagging behind standards

I could reproduce/fix your animation by removing **leading white space** in the `keytimes` attribute values as found in:

**Update**: As commented by Robert Longson:
Per [SMIL 3.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/smil30.html#smil-animation-animationNS-SplineAttrs%20Whitespace) **additional white space should be ignored** – so it should to be considered a [webkit bug.](https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs)

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0; 1 1; 0 0" keyTimes="0 ; .4 ; 1" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
```

```css
body{
  background:#ccc
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="1.691 0 12.029 10.111" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
  <symbol id="star1" viewBox="0 0 4 4" width="5" height="5">
    <g>
      <path transform-origin="1.5 1.5" fill="white" d="M 0 0 C 1 1 1 2 0 3 C 1 2 2 2 3 3 C 2 2 2 1 3 0 C 2 1 1 1 0 0">
        <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="scale" values="0 0; 1 1; 0 0" keyTimes="0; .4; 1" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 1.5 1.5; 90 1.5 1.5" keyTimes="0; 1" dur="1s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </g>
  </symbol>
  <use transform="matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 2.0000000298023224, 1.0000000149011612)" href="#star1">
  </use>
</svg>
```

### (SVG) Spec versions are seldom helpful

SVG 2 is still "in flux" (same applies to something like CSS 3) – besides, these spec versions usually don't help to fix any browser specific rendering issues.

Modern browsers (Firefox, blink/chromium, webkit) usually support many features introduced by the SVG 2 spec.

However, there is no standard how to implement these format recommendations.
Some browsers may implement concepts sooner – others may wait until the specs are perfectly clear.

### Debugging recommendations for svg animations

- Reduce your svg to a single element and
- test each animation to find the one that doesn't work
- inspect all attribute values closely – do `values` and `keyTimes` match?
- any "non-ideal"  whitespace?
- ["SVG Presentation Attributes"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/Presentation) defined via CSS – still not supported by browser XYZ

Comment: You want the [SMIL 3.0 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-smil/smil30.html#smil-animation-animationNS-SplineAttrs) - *In the calcMode, keyTimes and keySplines attribute values, leading and trailing white space and white space before and after semicolon separators will be ignored*. So that's a webkit bug.

Comment: @Robert Longso: Thanks for your feedback! (See update) Don't get me wrong: webkit/safari should definitely catch up in many attempts - I just disagree with the popular and unhelpful consensus that assumes "... ah! must be a Safari bug, it's kinda the new ie". My point was to illustrate that a lot of Safari/webkit related problems can be easily solved by just being "stricter" without using ugly hacks like browser detection etc. There is actually no need to write keytimes separated by leading/trailing whitespace like this - although standardised tolerances are great.

Comment: I find that anything that doesn't match Chrome is reported as a bug ;-)